# MySQL Query to Search using LIMIT and OFFSET on each Query of a UNION

Tags: mysql

This is more of a concept question I guess.

```
* discussion
discussionId
message
timestamp

* comment
commentId
message
timestamp

* tweet
tweetId
message
timestamp
```

Then on a page I list the first let's say 10 entries and with next will load the next 10. All normal there.

My question is: Is there a way to limit each query of the UNION or I can only do the LIMIT/OFFSET on the result of the UNION? I'm pondering because I was imagining if each table has like 1K (I know the number is very low), the query would return 3K results and then grab only 10. When the number of rows gets bigger, it wouldn't slow down the performance? Or even if in the future there are more tables that I want to do the UNION, it wouldn't be better to get x of each one of then and in the end get the desired 10? But I can't figure it out how I'll know which one was the last one of the limit/offset of the queries... so I'm afraid I would have to select all and use the limit on the UNION.

So instead of using

```
(SELECT 
    message,
    timestamp
FROM 
    discussion
)

UNION

(SELECT 
    message,
    timestamp
FROM 
    comment
)
UNION

(SELECT 
    message,
    timestamp
FROM 
    tweet
)
LIMIT $offset, $limit
```

Is it possible to have

```
(SELECT 
    message,
    timestamp
FROM 
    discussion
    LIMIT $offset, $limit
)

UNION

(SELECT 
    message,
    timestamp
FROM 
    comment
    LIMIT $offset, $limit
)
UNION

(SELECT 
    message,
    timestamp
FROM 
    tweet
    LIMIT $offset, $limit
)
LIMIT $offset, $limit
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's possible to have something like this but I think this will not work as expected...offset will be out of limit for each table at some point and also, the last offset-limit will be done only on partial result. It will not be consistent

Comment: If you have control over the db design, I suggest to put all of this in the same table...or at least create a view

Comment: Hi @FabienTheSolution if it was on the same table, and I wanted to pull specific information for each type of message, how I would achieve that based on the type of the message. Let's say we the table entry with rows entry_id, entry_type, timestamp. And then we pull using entry_type other information pertinent to that type, would be ending up being the same case? Thanks!

Comment: Check the answer I just post

Comment: How could we test both solutions to see performance? Because I think that Views @FabienTheSolution have some restrictions on creating index, and LEFT OUTER JOINS are not so fast. By the other hand, I have three nested SELECTS, and that is not either very good. And lately, we have just retrieve all and go with a limit, XDDDD. Which one will be better?

Comment: Yes, you're right about index restriction. Look the comment post by Manolo Guerrero on this page, may be it could be done in your case : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html ... BTW...there is no obligation to create a VIEW, you can just use the SELECT itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353d6/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Message
    (`id` int, `type_id` int, `message` varchar(10), `timestamp` int)
;

INSERT INTO Message
    (`id`, `type_id`, `message`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'message1', 12345678),
    (2, 2, 'message2', 12345679),
    (3, 3, 'message3', 12345680)
;


CREATE TABLE Type
    (`id` int, `type` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Type
    (`id`, `type`)
VALUES
    (1, 'discussion'),
    (2, 'comment'),
    (3, 'tweet')
;


CREATE TABLE DiscussionDetail
    (`id` int, `message_id` int, `from_user` varchar(10), `to_user` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO DiscussionDetail
    (`id`, `message_id`, `from_user`, `to_user`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Peter', 'Anna')
;


CREATE TABLE CommentDetail
    (`id` int, `message_id` int, `post_id` varchar(5), `user_id` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO CommentDetail
    (`id`, `message_id`, `post_id`, `user_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 'post4', 'user6')
;


CREATE TABLE TweetDetail
    (`id` int, `message_id` int, `twitteracct` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO TweetDetail
    (`id`, `message_id`, `twitteracct`)
VALUES
    (1, 3, 'myacct')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Message.*, type,
case when dd.id is not null then from_user 
     when cd.id is not null then post_id  
     when td.id is not null then twitteracct else '' end as detail1,
case when dd.id is not null then to_user  
     when cd.id is not null then user_id else '' end as detail2
FROM Message
INNER JOIN Type ON Type_Id = Type.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN DiscussionDetail dd ON dd.message_id = Message.id AND Type_Id = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CommentDetail cd ON cd.message_id = Message.id AND Type_Id = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN TweetDetail td ON td.message_id = Message.id AND Type_Id = 3
ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1,1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353d6/5/0)**:

```
| id | type_id |  message | timestamp |    type | detail1 | detail2 |
|----|---------|----------|-----------|---------|---------|---------|
|  2 |       2 | message2 |  12345679 | comment |   post4 |   user6 |
```

You can also create a VIEW for this :

```
CREATE VIEW AllMessages AS
SELECT Message.*, type,
case when dd.id is not null then from_user 
     when cd.id is not null then post_id  
     when td.id is not null then twitteracct else '' end as detail1,
case when dd.id is not null then to_user  
     when cd.id is not null then user_id else '' end as detail2
FROM Message
INNER JOIN Type ON Type_Id = Type.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN DiscussionDetail dd ON dd.message_id = Message.id AND Type_Id = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CommentDetail cd ON cd.message_id = Message.id AND Type_Id = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN TweetDetail td ON td.message_id = Message.id AND Type_Id = 3
```

And then :

```
SELECT *
FROM AllMessages
ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1,1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3242b/1)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for this, it shines a light! Adding another complexity to the solution. I copy and made it more beginners understanding your solution and added a table Forum to it, where the forum_id is on the Comment, Discussion table but not on the Tweet. Please see at the end of the schema. How would you modify the query to have the Forum name in the result? Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @fabien-thesolution I added a LEFT JOIN Forum ON (Forum.id = Discussion.forum_id OR Forum.id = Comment.forum_id) it worked, but it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I like your question and I myself asked that once. I used the second solution of retrieving all and then paginate what I needed. Now, the problem is the performance, so here I will try to improve the performance of retrieving the rows, with several thousands of rows (this solution have to be tested, but I think it will work smoothly).

The tricky performance idea: Create a new table, only with ids of the tables, look for the timestamp (or the column that every table share and you use for ordering) and then filter by that. This way, you will have this:

```
SELECT insert_time
FROM all_tables_order 
ORDER BY insert_time DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

From there, you take the boundaries (First and last row result, to take the insert_time, you may see that in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/043c1/29), and then you create the big SQL, with that limits:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.id as id,
          t.tweet as message,
          t.insert_time as insert_time
    FROM tweets t
    WHERE insert_time <= '2015-08-06 21:53:30' 
    AND insert_time >= '2015-08-06 21:51:34'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.id as id,
          c.`comment` as message,
          c.insert_time as insert_time
    FROM comments c
    WHERE insert_time <= '2015-08-06 21:53:30' 
    AND insert_time >= '2015-08-06 21:51:34'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT m.id as id,
          m.message as message,
          m.insert_time as insert_time
     FROM messages m 
     WHERE insert_time <= '2015-08-06 21:53:30' 
     AND insert_time >= '2015-08-06 21:51:34'
) AS myWholeTable
ORDER BY insert_time
```

This should be quite fast, despite the fact you're doing two queries, because your results are indexed, and you're only ordering small results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/043c1/30

Your database schema should have something like the following, with the triggers there to update the indexes table:

#### Tables and datas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `all_tables_order` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `insert_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `table_name` enum('comments','tweets','messages') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `all_tables_order` (`id`, `insert_time`, `table_name`) VALUES
    (1, '2015-08-06 21:50:52', 'messages'),
    (2, '2015-08-06 21:51:34', 'comments'),
    (1, '2015-08-06 21:52:10', 'tweets'),
    (2, '2015-08-06 21:52:46', 'messages'),
    (2, '2015-08-06 21:53:07', 'tweets'),
    (3, '2015-08-06 21:53:30', 'comments'),
    (1, '2015-08-03 21:53:39', 'comments');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment` tinytext CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `insert_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `Índice 1` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `comment`, `insert_time`) VALUES
    (2, 'c1', '2015-08-06 21:51:34'),
    (3, 'c3', '2015-08-06 21:53:30'),
    (1, 'c2', '2015-08-03 21:53:39');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` tinytext,
  `insert_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `Índice 1` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `message`, `insert_time`) VALUES
    (1, 'm1', '2015-08-06 21:50:52'),
    (2, 'm2', '2015-08-06 21:52:46');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tweets` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tweet` tinytext,
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `insert_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `Índice 1` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

INSERT INTO `tweets` (`id`, `tweet`, `created_by`, `insert_time`) VALUES
    (1, 't1', 23, '2015-08-06 21:52:10'),
    (2, 't2', 25, '2015-08-06 21:53:07');
```

#### Triggers:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `comments_before_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `comments` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    insert into all_tables_order set insert_time = new.insert_time, id = new.id, table_name = 'comments';
END//
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TRIGGER `messages_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `messages` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    insert into all_tables_order set insert_time = new.insert_time, id = new.id, table_name = 'messages';
END//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tweets_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `tweets` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    insert into all_tables_order set insert_time = new.insert_time, id = new.id, table_name = 'tweets';
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I think this will not work as expected...the whole result need also to be sort....and offset will be out of limit for each table at some point...

Comment: @FabienTheSolution, wow, you´re right! Wth did I do?? :P. I´m going to look for my code and I´ll be back...

Comment: Hi I agree with @FabienTheSolution and that was the same thing I was thinking... that at some point it would be missing results from the inside querys and therefore on the final result. And that's why I got to this impasse.

Comment: @Chococroc...yep...I think your idea could lead to somthing :)

Comment: Wooooorking on it, ;P

Comment: Done, I think that works. My concern is about having three nested selects, that may hit performance. But on the other hand, are quite small queries that may be executed quite fast, with INNER JOIN, that is also pretty quick.

Comment: Hi @Chococroc thanks for taking the time! I changed the values of the dates to test it. And one thing is that when is the second page it would be LIMIT 2,2 right? So I  changed to that, and it shows only 1 row, disregarding the other rows on the table, the result should be for a LIMIT 2,2 c1 and t1. If you leave LIMIT 0,2 it shows 6 results, while the result should be m1 and c2 if I'm not mistaken. What do you think?

Comment: I think I made the same mistake overcomplicating the SQL, :/. What about having the timestamp from the index table, and then just looking for the results with that timestamp as a WHERE restriction? This makes two SQL queries, but very small...

Comment: @Chococroc yeah I think it was too complicated, but it help clarify the problem so I gave you a +1! Thanks so much!